# JScrollPane randomly fails to display contents

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a problem with a JScrollPane. It will randomly choose to display or not display. There are two test areas each in their own scrollpane. One thing of note it will become visible if I resize the JFrame. When it runs the 1 box or the two box may not be visible. 40% of the time box 2 will be visible but not 1. 30% of the time box 1 will be visible but not 2. 20% of the time both boxes will be visible. 10% of the time neither of the boxes will be visible. These are rough numbers but it seems to be generally close. I have run the program multiple times, with and without recompiling, the results change even though the code has not. I have tried this with and without a layout manager the results are the same. I'd like to avoid the comments like "You MUST use a layout manager or pixies will cut out your eyes". I have a "frame.repaint();" at the end. Here is the code excerpt.

```
JTextArea area1 = new JTextArea(  );
area1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
area1.setText("1");
area1.setVisible( true );
JScrollPane scroll1;
scroll1 = new JScrollPane(area1);
scroll1.setLocation( 1, 1 );
scroll1.setSize( (frame.getSize().width / 2) - 2 , frame.getSize().height - 40 );
area1.repaint();
scroll1.revalidate();
scroll1.repaint();
scroll1.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
scroll1.setVisible( true );
frame.add(scroll1);
```

I have tried too many, to remember, things I have found from looking on the net. If I use "JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(area1);" instead, the results are the same. If I use "scroll1.add(area1);" and not add it to the constructor it will not ever show the contents of the scroll pane. I've also tried setting it to visible false adding it then making it visible, the results are the same. At this point I am at a loss for why this is happening, it is even more that the results will be different between runs. And you know what they say about insanity...

Does anyone know how to fix this?
here is a pic from one of the runs.

[image]

[Here is a shared JAR file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4JSHhNONAZuWjhOOWdLazBIc2M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try putting `frame.setVisible(true);` at the end of the code, after `frame.add(scroll1)`. Always works for me.

Comment: ? Using a `null` layout possibility ? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer I can do that, I have a JAR file that I will upload.

Comment: Nope, prefer a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which I can copy and paste into my IDE and have a play with

Comment: @TheCoffeeKid that works, its a bit odd but I just ran it 10 or so times and no more errors. Can you pose that as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: The JAR file has the source code so you could import that into the IDE of your choice.

Comment: "Randomly fails to display contents" is usually a symptom of making changes to the GUI on a thread other than the event thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `frame.setVisible(true);` at the end of your code, after `frame.add(scroll1)`. That always works for me.

Comment: This solution works, I've never had to do that before but it does work now.